# PHP - Perl compatible regexp

Tags: php, regex, validation, filter, email-validation

How do I turn this regexp

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

from this site: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

into a Perl compatible regexp required by PHP in the filter_var function under FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP?

If I just add it to the options as-is I get this error: 
filter_var() [function.filter-var]: Unknown modifier '+' in ...

Comment: I'd love it if those who downvoted this explained themselves a bit so I don't make the same mistake again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the expression with a [delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) (`/` is most commonly used):

```
/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/
```

Comment: And escape all occurences of said delimiter in the regex body.

Comment: Have you actually tried that regex?

Comment: That worked, thanks, and escaping was necessary, DCoder was right.

Comment: @DCoder:  My mistake, could have sworn it wasn't required. Thanks for the heads-up!